# Django bootstrap dropdown button in navbar not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've tried other questions with similar topic with many different links to bootstrap but it was not working for me, none of them. Any clues why my dropdown button does not roll down when clicked (also does not when hovered either as this was the case for some people).

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/stylesheet.css' %}">
    <title>
        Milk - {% block title_block %}Milk Students{% endblock %}
    </title>
    
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
                <!-- Navbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark py-1">

                <a class="navbar-brand p-2" href="{% url 'milk_app:home' %}">MilkStudents</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:home' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:about' %}">About</a></li>

                        <!-- If the user is logged in, either as HOST or TENANT he gets these buttons available -->
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                          </button>
                          
                          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                  Dropdown
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:logout' %}">Log out</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:profile' %}">View Profile</a></li>                        
                            
                        <!-- Otherwise he can either log-in/register -->
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                        {% endif %}

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">


        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-2">

                    {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}

                    <!-- FOOTER -->
                    
                    <footer class="fixed-bottom">
                        <p> &copy; MilkStudents.com &middot; <a href="{% url 'milk_app:careers' %}" class="footer-href">Careers</a> &middot; <a href="{% url 'milk_app:contact' %}" class="footer-href">Contact Us &middot;</a> <a href="{% url 'milk_app:FAQ' %}" class="footer-href" >FAQ</a> {% if user.is_authenticated %}&middot; LOGGED USER: {{user.username}} &middot; ROLE: {{user.userprofile.account}}{%endif%} </p>
                    </footer>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.9.0/feather.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Enables the popover buttons everywhere -->
        <script>
            $(function () {
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })
        </script>
        <!-- Enables the tooltips everywhere -->
        <script>
            var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
            var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The  are linked at the bottom.

Comment: Does your html+css(bootstrap) code works properly?

Comment: yes, as far I know

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, I replaced your code for dropdown using code from [bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) and it works like a charm. Recheck your code for the dropdown.... entire `div` ( `id="navbarNavDarkDropdown" `)  is wrong. You're defining entire new `nav` instead of dropdown\

Comment: I have the one I pasted in the code also from the bootstrap doc. None from the doc work for me here

Comment: Well you did copy the entire nav instead of drop down

Comment: yes, I did copy the whole thing

Comment: You really need to do some research instead of ctrl+c, ctrl + v

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining entire collapsible Nav,

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it should look like this,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/stylesheet.css' %}">
    <title>
        Milk - 
    </title>
    
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
                <!-- Navbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark py-1">

                <a class="navbar-brand p-2" href="{% url 'milk_app:home' %}">MilkStudents</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:home' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:about' %}">About</a></li>

                        <!-- If the user is logged in, either as HOST or TENANT he gets these buttons available -->
                        <!-- #
                             # ------- HERE -------------
                             #
                              -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- ----END of dropdown --- -->

                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:logout' %}">Log out</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:profile' %}">View Profile</a></li>                        
                            
                        <!-- Otherwise he can either log-in/register -->
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'milk_app:login' %}">Login</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">


        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-2">

                    {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}

                    <!-- FOOTER -->
                    
                    <footer class="fixed-bottom">
                        <p> &copy; MilkStudents.com &middot; <a href="{% url 'milk_app:careers' %}" class="footer-href">Careers</a> &middot; <a href="{% url 'milk_app:contact' %}" class="footer-href">Contact Us &middot;</a> <a href="{% url 'milk_app:FAQ' %}" class="footer-href" >FAQ</a> {% if user.is_authenticated %}&middot; LOGGED USER: {{user.username}} &middot; ROLE: {{user.userprofile.account}}{%endif%} </p>
                    </footer>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.9.0/feather.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Enables the popover buttons everywhere -->
        <script>
            $(function () {
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })
        </script>
        <!-- Enables the tooltips everywhere -->
        <script>
            var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
            var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does literally nothing with the dropdown button for me